# How can I adjust the code so it takes advantage of a GPU on an 2013 Mac?

Tags: c, performance, gpu, gpgpu

I have an 2013 Mac computer with

```
Processor: 2,7 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7 

 Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB
```

shown in its "About this Mac" description. I guess that means my machine has a GPU. Now, I am working with a piece of code that looks like a Taylor expansion:

```
double taylor(int n, double x) { 
    double exp_sum = 1;     
    for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; --i ) 
        exp_sum = 1 + x * exp_sum / i;    
    return exp_sum; 
}
```

How can I adjust the code so it takes advantage of this GPU to accelerate my computation? People do some special adjustment and compilation with CUDA. But I wonder how one could adjust the code and compilation for this ad-hoc GPU?

Comment: Can that GPU compute with `double` or is it limited to `float`?

Comment: @WeatherVane Good question! I suppose it can compute with double since the host machine can. The host machine is a 2013 Mac.

Comment: The computation is done on the graphics processor, not the host's cpu. An answer on another [SE stack](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/6853/do-currently-available-gpus-support-double-precision-floating-point-arithmetic) says: *Double precision is fairly common on newer GPUs.*

Comment: It's not trivial.

Comment: My point was that only the newer GPUs have double precision. The older ones used single precision as a trade-off between speed and accuracy.

Comment: @WeatherVane Not sure what you mean by "the computation is done on the graphics processor, not the host's cpu".  If I just compile and run, the code should run with CPU; now I would like to know how to let GPU do the work instead. Is that doable?

Comment: I see you point on double vs float. Thanks for the info. So, how could I know if this GPU uses float or double?

Comment: You said yourself: *I want to use the GPU*. That is not the CPU. You cannot make the assumption that because the CPU can use `double` the GPU can. They are distinct devices.

Comment: @zell Code doesn't use the GPU automatically.  At one level, code must be specially, separately compiled for the GPU, and control flow explicitly transferred from CPU to GPU and back.  For NVIDIA GPUs, there's a whole set of language extensions called CUDA that helps you do this.  There's also a higher-level, device-independent parallel-processing paradigm that I forget the name of but someone will probably mention soon.

Comment: @SteveSummit You are right. I see people do some separate code and compilation with CUDA. But how could I adjust the code and compilation for this ad-hoc GPU?

Comment: @zell I would start by reading the [CUDA programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html) and/or tutorial.  (What's an "ad-hoc GPU"?  The GPUs I know of are extremely specific, pretty much the opposite of "ad hoc".)

Comment: "CUDA works with all Nvidia GPUs from the G8x series onwards, including GeForce, Quadro and the Tesla line." The GPU on my 2013 Mac does not seem from NVidia.

Comment: Maybe read about [General-purpose computing on graphics processing units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units), then.  Also about [OpenMP](https://www.openmp.org/) and/or [OpenCL](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/).

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** this code can hardly be parallelized, especially on GPU. Even if it is possible to parallelize it, it would slower on your GPU (for DP precision) compared to a parallel CPU implementation.

---

The Intel HD Graphics 4000 is an Integrated Graphic Processing Unit (IGPU) supporting OpenCL 1.2. It supports both simple and double precision. That being said, double precision (DP) is much slower than simple precision (SP) like on most GPUs (including client-side AMD/Nvidia ones but not some expensive server-side GPUs made for scientific computing). In practice, it can do computations at the speed of 256 GFLOPS for SP and 64 GFLOPS for DP.

Your processor is certainly an Intel Core [i7-3740QM](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/70847/intel-core-i73740qm-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-70-ghz/specifications.html). This Ivy bridge processor can do 8 DP FLOPs/cycle and 16 SP FLOPs/cycle. This means `4 * 2.7e9 * 8 = 86.4` GFLOPS in DP and `4 * 2.7e9 * 16 = 172.8` GFLOPS in SP for the base frequency. In turbo, this can be up to 37% better but not all core can be in max turbo mode and also not for a long time anyway (not to mention the processor temperature can impact this). Assuming the optimal turbo frequency can be reached on all cores, it would mean 118.4 and 236.7 GFLOPS for respectively DP and SP.

As you can see, the CPU can compute DP codes faster than the GPU so **the DP computation will be significantly slower on your GPU**. This is common on PCs (as opposed to computing servers). That being said, the computation can be slightly faster in SP on the GPU (though it certainly do not worth the effort of writing a GPU kernel for that on your machine). IGPU are generally good for offloading part of the graphical pipeline that would be expensive to do on the CPU like rasterization and texturing. They are also good to reduce the power consumption but do not shine for speed.

This is actually much bigger problem: **the loop has a sequential dependency chain so it cannot be easily parallelized** (neither on the CPU, nor the GPU which are massively parallel). Even worse: the computation is **latency bound** and limited by the speed of the **slow division** (whatever the target device). You can **pre-compute the inverse value `x / i` so to make the computation less latency bound**. This can be done in parallel and vectorized (so certainly up to 8 times faster on your CPU). You can do that with OpenMP. That being said, the code will be still be bounded by the latency of `exp_sum = 1 + precomputed_factor[i] * exp_sum` dependency chain. It is certainly a good idea to use another formula for this taylor serie if possible: one that can be computed in parallel.